# Why cannot I cast (String) -> String to (Any) -> Any in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, casting

Since `Any` can hold any type, and String is a lower type, why cannot I cast a `(String) -> String` function to `(Any) -> Any` function?

```
func lower(_ s: String) -> String {
    return s.lowercased()
}

func upper(_ s: String) -> String {
    return s.uppercased()
}

func foo(_ s: @escaping (Any) -> Any) -> (Any) -> Any {
    return s
}


let f = foo(lower as! (Any) -> Any)  // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.

f("ABC")
```

Comment: Upcasting to `Any` is horrible. How about generics or a protocol solution?

Comment: Think about it: `let anyFunc = lower as! (Any) -> Any` would be a function that can take arbitrary arguments ...

Comment: Yes, I am looking to write a `comp` function which takes any number of functions and it's up to the functions in the list to order the arguments properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since `Any` can hold any type, and String is a lower type, why cannot I cast a `(String) -> String` function to `(Any) -> Any` function?

Because the two have nothing to do with each other.

Yes, it is true that `String` <: `Any`. Which means that you can cast `String` to `Any`. But you are not trying to cast `String` to `Any`. You are trying to cast `(String) -> String` to `(Any) -> Any`, which are *two completely different types* from `String` and `Any`. `(String) -> String` is not the same as `String` and `(Any) -> Any` is not the same as `Any`, so there is absolutely no reason why a relationship that holds for `String` and `Any` should also automatically hold for `(String) -> String` and `(Any) -> Any` … and as you found out, the relationship does, in fact, *not* hold.

The short answer is: functions are contravariant in their parameter types and covariant in their return type. Therefore, `(String) -> String` would be a *subtype* of `(String) -> Any` and a *supertype* of `(Any) -> String` and it is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `(Any) -> Any`.

In the early 1970s, a computer scientist named Barbara Liskov invented a new way of thinking about subtyping in terms of *behaviorial substitution* that we now call the *Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP)*. We can use the LSP to explain exactly *why* functions are contravariant in their parameter types and covariant in their return type. (Note: this was well-known even before Liskov, but the LSP gives us a nice way of explaining why it is so.)

[Barbara Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) tells us that a type `S` is a subtype of type `T` **IFF** any instance of `T` can be replaced with an instance of `S` without changing the observable desirable properties of the program.

Let's take a simple generic type, a function. A function has two type parameters, one for the input, and one for the output. (We are keeping it simple here.) `(A) -> B` is a function that takes in an argument of type `A` and returns a result of type `B`.

And now we play through a couple of scenarios. I have some operation **O** that wants to work with a function from `Fruit`s to `Mammal`s (yeah, I know, exciting original examples!) The LSP says that I should also be able to pass in a subtype of that function, and everything should still work. Let's say, functions were covariant in `A`. Then I should be able to pass in a function from `Apple`s to `Mammal`s as well. But what happens when **O** passes an `Orange` to the function? That should be allowed! **O** was able to pass an `Orange` to `(Fruit) -> Mammal` because `Orange` is a subtype of `Fruit`. But, a function from `Apple`s doesn't know how to deal with `Orange`s, so it blows up. The LSP says it should work though, which means that the only conclusion we can draw is that our assumption is wrong: `(Apple) -> Mammal` is not a subtype of `(Fruit)-> Mammal`, in other words, functions are not covariant in `A`.

What if it were contravariant? What if we pass a `(Food) -> Mammal` into **O**? Well, **O** again tries to pass an `Orange` and it works: `Orange` is a `Food`, so `(Food) -> Mammal)` knows how to deal with `Orange`s. We can now conclude that functions are *contravariant* in their inputs, i.e. you can pass a function that takes a more general type as its input as a replacement for a function that takes a more restricted type and everything will work out fine.

Now let's look at the return type of the function. What would happen if functions were contravariant in `B` just like they are in `A`? We pass a `(Fruit) -> Animal` to **O**. According to the LSP, if we are right and functions are contravariant in their return type, nothing bad should happen. Unfortunately, **O** calls the `getMilk` method on the result of the function, but the function just returned it a `Chicken`. Oops. Ergo, functions can't be contravariant in their return types.

OTOH, what happens if we pass a `(Fruit) -> Cow`? Everything still works! **O** calls `getMilk` on the returned cow, and it indeed gives milk. So, it looks like functions are covariant in their outputs.

And that is a general rule that applies to variance:

- It is safe (in the sense of the LSP) to make `C<A>` *covariant* in `A` **IFF** `A` is used *only* as an output.
- It is safe (in the sense of the LSP) to make `C<A>` *contravariant* in `A` **IFF** `A` is used *only* as an input.
- If `A` can be used either as an input or as an output, then `C<A>` *must* be invariant in `A`, otherwise the result is not safe.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation of the concepts.